# Why is Android app with Jetpack Compose, Room and Dagger-Hilt crashing?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-room, dagger-hilt

I'm making an Android app with **Jetpack Compose**, **Room** and **Dagger-Hilt**.
The app crashes with following exception:

```java
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find implementation for com.pbpu.android.data.local.source.Database. Database_Impl does not exist
```

Project level `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.10" apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.8.10-1.0.9" apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.47" apply false
}
```

The dependencies used are:

```kotlin
//    DI
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.47")
    ksp("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.47")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0")
//    Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.2")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.2")
    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2")
//    Other dependencies
```

If I change dependencies to:

```kotlin
//    DI
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.47")
    ksp("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.47")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0")
//    Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.2")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.2")
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2")
//    Other dependencies
```

Then compilation fails with message:

```java
path\to\file\RecordWithMarkingsDao.java:17: error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
    com.pbpu.android.domain.model.RecordWithMarkings entity, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
                                                     ^
```

But, same code compiles if I use `ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2")` or even `annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2")` but then, the app crashes with exception as stated before!

`Record.kt`

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName = "records")
data class Record(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    var idRecord: Long = 0,
//    Other fields
)
```

`Marking.kt`

```kotlin
@Entity(
    tableName = "markings",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Record::class,
            parentColumns = ["idRecord"],
            childColumns = ["fkIdRecord"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
        ),
    ],
)
data class Marking(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    var idMarking: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    val fkIdRecord: Long = 0,
//    Other fields
)
```

`RecordWithMarkings.kt`

```kotlin
data class RecordWithMarkings(
    @Embedded
    val record: Record,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "idRecord",
        entityColumn = "fkIdRecord",
    )
    val markings: List<Marking>,
)
```

How to solve this problem?

Any help will be appreciated and ask for any additional information if required.

Thanks.

Comment: i think you have not added @Entity annotation on data class which you are using as as a table in database

Comment: No, actually it is a middle class which includes `@Embedded` and `@Relation` and don't need `@Entity` annotation (At least this is what I've seen in many tutorials online).
I've added the code for those classes in the question.

Comment: Still, I tried adding `@Entity` to the class in `RecordWithMarkings.kt` but, it gives error as: `error: Entities cannot have relations.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the issue is in the DAO, please ensure correctness:

- The `RecordWithMarkingsDao.java` should have methods that deal with fetching `RecordWithMarkings` objects. These methods should return `RecordWithMarkings` or a list of `RecordWithMarkings` but shouldn't take `RecordWithMarkings` as an argument. Here is an example of what the DAO might look like:

```
@Dao
interface RecordWithMarkingsDao {

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM records")
    fun getAllRecordsWithMarkings(): List<RecordWithMarkings>

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM records WHERE idRecord = :recordId")
    fun getRecordWithMarkings(recordId: Long): RecordWithMarkings
}
```

- for CRUD operations use separate DAOs (or methods within the same DAO) that work directly with the `Record` and `Marking` entities, for example:

```
@Dao
interface RecordDao {

    @Insert
    fun insertRecord(record: Record): Long

    @Update
    fun updateRecord(record: Record)

    @Delete
    fun deleteRecord(record: Record)
}

@Dao
interface MarkingDao {

    @Insert
    fun insertMarking(marking: Marking): Long

    @Update
    fun updateMarking(marking: Marking)

    @Delete
    fun deleteMarking(marking: Marking)
}
```

This should help :)

Comment: Yeah, seems like I overlooked the official tutorial which didn't include insert or update methods in middle class DAO but only read functions.